# Openstack LXC containers missing DNS

Tags: juju, dns, maas, openstack, lxc

In my newly deployed openstack environment, I noticed that CEPH was failing within the 3 LXC containers.

```
016-05-03 02:18:38 INFO juju-log Unknown hook update-status - skipping.
Reading package lists... Donete-status 
Building dependency tree       -status 
Reading state information... Donetatus 
2016-05-03 02:18:40 INFO update-status sudo: unable to resolve host juju-machine-1-lxc-3
```

[image]

Any ideas?  Is it standard that the physical nodes wouldn't be able to DNS the containers?  Seems highly unlikely, and also, when I deployed the same setup before, I didn't have any issue.  I'm guessing the DNS is why I am getting the HEALTH_WARN error.

Update: I've discovered the DNS error isn't actually why CEPH is failing, so I'm interested in both.  Should DNS entries be added to Bind for the containers, not just physical hosts?  Any idea on why Ceph might be failing?

Update 2:  Ceph is failing because the placement groups exceed the PG max set by ceph.  The fix is increase the OSDs without increasing the placement groups.  I've added an answer that indicates the bug.  The suggestion at the time of this edit, is to create some tuning in the juju charm to 'calibrate' settings after things are deployed.

Update 3:  Adding OSD's does decrease the placement groups count against the maximum PG limit warning value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help, I was able to find this bug, which was what was causing the health_warn in ceph.  I haven't resolved the error yet with a work around, but I'll update this answer when I do.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/glance/+bug/1492742

Adding OSDs will resolve the warning.  The nice part is, juju handles it all for you.  Once the drive is put into the server, maas and juju play nice, and make it immediately an OSD.

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-0-lxc-4:~$ sudo ceph status
    cluster eabab000-231c-4edb-855c-dd30b1bab56d
     health HEALTH_OK
     monmap e2: 3 mons at {juju-machine-0-lxc-4=10.14.0.53:6789/0,juju-machine-1-lxc-0=10.14.0.62:6789/0,juju-machine-2-lxc-4=10.14.0.60:6789/0}
            election epoch 12, quorum 0,1,2 juju-machine-0-lxc-4,juju-machine-2-lxc-4,juju-machine-1-lxc-0
     osdmap e356: 13 osds: 13 up, 13 in
      pgmap v133686: 1091 pgs, 14 pools, 101133 MB data, 26747 objects
            278 GB used, 3735 GB / 4014 GB avail
                1091 active+clean
```